# Why my servo motor is always on?

Tags: servo, button

Why my servo motor is always on?

[image: Schematic]

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;

int pos = 0;

void setup() {

pinMode(2, INPUT);
myservo.attach(9);

}

void loop() {

  if (digitalRead(2) == LOW) {

    for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) {
      myservo.write(pos);
      delay(15);
    }

    for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) {
      myservo.write(pos);
      delay(15);
    }
  }
  else {
    myservo.write(0);
    delay(15);
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide a proper schematic and listing.

Comment: What do you mean by 'always on', is it always moving or always energized?

Comment: Voting to close because it is unclear what you're asking.  Please answer @JackCreasey's question, and maybe we can help.

Comment: @TimWescott Why not simply give the OP the opportunity to alter the question rather than hastily 'close' the question. Once closed it seems unlikely to get votes to open again even if it is altered. This is really just 'close' being used as a form of bullying.

Comment: @JackCreasey I did not invent Stackexchange, or its rules.  I just follow them.  As was pointed out to me when I asked just your question, closed questions *do* get reopened when they are fixed up.

Comment: Drastically simplify your setup.  Take the condition out of the code and just command a steady angle.  Then try again with a different one.  As you make your sketch more complicated again, add serial logging to explain what it thinks it is doing.  And of course explain **precisely what is happening**.

Comment: Closing would prevent a bunch of well-intended but poorly informed (no info from OP) answers to be written and made obsolete by updates on the question and context.

Comment: @JackCreasey it's always moving sorry i'm didn't know much

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to enable the pull-up resistor on D2.  As written D2 is left floating and most likely is a low voltage relative to ground.  Enabling the pull up resistor will force the pin high until you flip the switch.

Comment: Arduino inputs have significant capacitance. So once the switch has been pressed the input will tend to stay low. Use either pinMode(pin, INPUT_PULLUP) or use digitalWrite(pin, HIGH) to turn on the pullup for a (pin) configured as INPUT.

Comment: it works!! thanks